# How can/should I host ratings inside of my app?

Tags: android, rating, review

I am making a yelp-like app in which users can discover local places and rate them, but I am having trouble on deciding how I should store the ratings for each place. What would be the best method of storing these ratings so that I can allow my users to see other users reviews?

Comment: Use Parse: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide an excellent key/value database that supports user's and retaining data. This requires internet access though. If you wanted just local data retention use SQLite, which comes with the standard Android SDK

Comment: No, local data is not viewable by users outside the local device. Local data retention means it only lives on your device (in the cached memory), for user's to see shared data amongst each other, it has to live on a server and served to all user's who query for it (as @Bojan Kseneman says). I suggest Parse for a simple implementation of this, as you can create custom objects to support all of this. With some witty implementation choices as well, of course.

Comment: Well Parse is simple, but you have to pay for it if you have loads of requests. Also you are giving 3rd party people unrestricted access to your data and that is why I will never use it on a production level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LucasCrawford, I have discovered parse, which should solve my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid if you want your users to see other users reviews, you will need a backed (server) and save the ratings there.

Also each rating should consist of a float value from 1 to 5 (because 2,5 is valid) and each rating should have a text). Make a SQL table to hold reviews and when the user want's to see the reviews, execute get all reviews for place in sql.